# How to connect the iphone to Itunes?

Tags: iphone

Iam trying to get the device id of my iphone.For that iam connecting iphone to MAc pc using datacable.But in itunes doesnt recognize my iphone.This iphone was bought in america and unlocked in india.i think this was the problem.If this is not a problem then please tell me the solution for that one.please sir.Apps are completed but testing is not completed because this is the problem.Please sir

Comment: I think it's a datacable problem not a phone problem

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to get my UDID from apps, so you may want to give this a try. The one that I used is called Ad Hoc Helper by Erica Sadun

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8